# Triangulation of a 3-manifold

Tags: mesh, triangulation, cgal

Is it possible to triangulate compact 3-manifolds like the 3-sphere into a simplicial complex using the CGAL library? If yes, where is the starting point?

Comment: Have you found an answer to your question, since you post it?

Answer (score 1):

You can start reading the CGAL chapter [3D Mesh Generation](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/index.html#Chapter_3D_Mesh_Generation) in [the CGAL manual](http://doc.cgal.org/). Maybe that can fit your needs.